# Error: Unexpected token 'layoutConstraints'. (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have just created a new Flutter project (freshly initialized), but when I run it, I encounter an error like this:

```
../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:953:89: Error: Unexpected token 'layoutConstraints'.
      'An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot 952 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity': An InputDecorator, which is typicall'
                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/kira/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

And when I try to create a new one, it always appears like that when I run it. What should I do?

I want my Flutter project to run smoothly. I have already upgraded Flutter, but it still doesn't work